# Proof of orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, orthogonal-matrices

Let $\alpha_1$,$\alpha_2$,...,$\alpha_s$ and $\beta_1$,$\beta_2$,..,$\beta_s$ be two families of vectors in $n$ dimensional Euclidean space $V$. Prove that the necessary and sufficient condition for an orthogonal transformation $\mathcal{A}$ to exist, such that
              \begin{equation}
               \mathcal{A}\alpha_i=\beta_i\qquad(i=1,2,...,s),
          \end{equation}
is that 
              \begin{equation}
               (\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=(\beta_i,\beta_j)\qquad(i,j=1,2,...,s).
          \end{equation}

The proof of necessity is easy. According to the definition of orthogonal transformation, for any inner product, we have 
               \begin{equation}
               (\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=(\mathcal{A}\alpha_i,\mathcal{A}\alpha_j)=(\beta_i,\beta_j)\qquad(i,j=1,2,...,s).
          \end{equation}

Comment: Are the $\alpha_i$ meant to span $V$? Are the $\beta_j$ meant to do so too?

Comment: $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are just two families of vectors in $V$. They are not meant to span $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis implies that for any scalars $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_s,y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_s$, we have

$$
\sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^s x_iy_j(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=
\sum_{i=1}^s \sum_{j=1}^s x_iy_j(\beta_i,\beta_j), \tag{1}
$$

or in other words,

$$
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^s x_i\alpha_i , \sum_{j=1}^s y_j\alpha_j \bigg)=
\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^s x_i\beta_i , \sum_{j=1}^s y_j\beta_j \bigg) \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

If we take $y_k=x_k$ in \eqref{2}, we deduce

$$
\bigg|\bigg| \sum_{k=1}^s x_k\alpha_k \bigg|\bigg|=
\bigg|\bigg| \sum_{k=1}^s x_k\beta_k \bigg|\bigg| \tag{3}
$$

and hence

$$
\sum_{k=1}^s x_k\alpha_k = 0 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^s x_k\beta_k = 0 \label{4}\tag{4}
$$

Since $\sum_{k=1}^s x_k\alpha_k=\sum_{k=1}^s y_k\alpha_k$ is equivalent to
$\sum_{k=1}^s (x_k-y_k)\alpha_k=0$, we deduce that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^s x_k\alpha_k = \sum_{k=1}^s y_k\alpha_k \Leftrightarrow \sum_{k=1}^s x_k\beta_k = \sum_{k=1}^s y_k\beta_k \label{5}\tag{5}
$$

Thus \eqref{5} tells us that there is a well-defined transformation $\cal A$ that sends every $\sum_{k=1}^s x_k\alpha_k$ to the corresponding $\sum_{k=1}^s x_k\beta_k $. And $\cal A$ is linear by construction.

If we put $x=\sum_{i=1}^s x_i\alpha_i$ and $y=\sum_{j=1}^s y_j\alpha_j$, we can now rewrite \eqref{2} as

$$
(x,y)=({\cal A}(x),{\cal A}(y)) \tag{6}
$$

So that $\cal A$ is an orthogonal transformation as wished.

Comment: There should be a comma before "or" whenever saying an equivalence. Otherwise, you're giving two options.

Comment: @mathworker21 Corrected, thx

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Your approach is simple. However, it is possible that $\alpha_{i}$ might not span the entire space. Therefore, we can not assume $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i} \alpha_{i}$.

Comment: @Inuyashayagami As it is now, thequestion nowhere asks for the transformation to be defined on the entire space - if this is your intention, you should add it in the question. This is no big deal anyway, as any orthogonal transformation defined on a subspace can be extended to an orthogonal transformation on the entire space - this follows from the fact that any orthogonal family can be completed into an orthogonal basis.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I just point out one thing here. $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$,...,$\alpha_s$ and $\beta_1$, $\beta_2$,...,$\beta_s$ are just two families of vectors in $E^n$. $s$ is not necessarily equal to $n$. And the rank $r$ of each family of vectors is not  necessarily equal to $s$. They are not necessarily linearly-independent vector families. So the deduction $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\alpha_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_k\alpha_k\Leftrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k-y_k)\alpha_k=0$ is not correct.

Comment: @RockLee I just point out two things here. 1) Confusion between $n$ and $s$ : corrected now, thx. 2) Yes the deduction $x=y \Leftrightarrow x-y=0$ is correct, you don't need any hypothesis at all on the $\alpha_k$.

The other things you mention are true but unrelated to m y proof - I nowhere use the rank of the family, nor do I assume that that they are linearly independent.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Dear Sir, I have added another answer to this question. The answer is similar to yours. Can you please check if that is correct. Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4126037/469530. Many thanks!

Comment: @Inuyasha Yagami Your proof is incorrect because your definition of $\cal A$ is incorrect. A definition must be unique, and when you say "Any vector $x$ in $V_{\alpha}$ can be expressed in the following form $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$ " the problem is that there may be more than one such form.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thanks for checking it. Although there can be multiple forms, the function is still bijective. If a vector $x$ has two forms say $\sum_{i = 1}^{s}a_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{s}b_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$; then both these forms will map to the same $\mathcal{A}(x)$. For the sake of contradiction, if these two maps to different vectors say $y = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}a_{i} \cdot \beta_{i}$ and $z = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}b_{i} \cdot \beta_{i}$. Then $\|y-z\| \neq 0$. It contradicts the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ preserves the pairwise distances.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Should I add proof of bijection also?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami You just need to add what you just said in your comment above.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The way you phrased it, the condition is only necessary for $A$ to be orthogonal, it is not sufficient. As a counterexample, consider the linear map $A\colon \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ defined by
$$
A(x, y, z)=(x, y, 0),$$
which is not orthogonal. However, the family $\alpha_1=(1, 0, 0), \alpha_2=(0, 1, 0)$ is mapped into itself, thus, with your notation, $\beta_1=\alpha_1, \beta_2=\alpha_2$ and obviously $(\alpha_i, \alpha_j)=(\beta_i, \beta_j)$ for all $i, j=1, 2$.

To fix the statement, you need to require that the family $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ is a **basis** of $V$. If this is the case, then every vector $x, y\in V$ can be written in a unique way as
$$
x=\sum_{j=1}^n x_j \alpha_j, \quad y=\sum_{j=1}^n y_k \alpha_k.$$
Using the assumption that $(A\alpha_j, A\alpha_k)=(\alpha_j, \alpha_k)$ we obtain
$$
\begin{split} 
(Ax, Ay)&= \sum\sum x_j y_k (A\alpha_j, A\alpha_k)\\
&= \sum\sum x_j y_k (\alpha_j, \alpha_k)\\
&=(\sum x_j\alpha_j, \sum y_k \alpha_k)=(x, y).\end{split}$$
This proves that $A$ is orthogonal.

Comment: I agree with you. However, note that the question is asking for existence of some orthogonal transformation. In your example, an Identity matrix can be a orthogonal transformation.

Comment: @Inuyashayagami: oh, I see. I misunderstood the question, then, and you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Define

$A_{(n\times s)}\equiv(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_s)$

$B_{(n\times s)}\equiv(\beta_1, \beta_2, ..., \beta_s)$

Write $A$ into $A = E_A \cdot S_A = O_A \cdot I_{k_A} \cdot S_A$

Here

- $E_A$ is the orthnomal base of $A$ after the Gram-Schmidt process
- $S_A$ is the matrix represent the Gram-Schmidt process operations for $A$.
- $I_{k_A} = \text{diag}\{1,1,...,1,0,...,0\}$ is a diagonal matrix with the first $k_A$ (the rank of A) elements being $1$ and the rest being $0$.
- $O_A$ is the orthogonal matrix that transform $I_{k_A}$ to $E_A$.

Because $(\alpha_i,\alpha_j) = (\beta_i, \beta_j)$,

- $A$ and $B$ share the same rank, i.e. $k_A = k_B$
- $A$ and $B$ share the same Gram-Schmidt process operations. i.e. $S_A = S_B$

So now if we define the orthogonal matrix $\mathcal{A} = O_B \cdot O_A^T$

Then we have
$\mathcal{A}\cdot A = O_B \cdot O_A^T \cdot O_A \cdot I_k \cdot S  = O_B \cdot I_k \cdot S = B$

which just means $\mathcal{A}\cdot\alpha_i = \beta_i$,  $\forall i\in(1,2,...,s)$

Answer (score 0):

The credit of this answer completely goes to [Ewan Delanoy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3854888/469530). I found that answer difficult to understand at first. Therefore, this is a simplified version
of that answer.

Let $V_{\alpha}$ be the space spanned by vectors $\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}, \dotsc, \alpha_{s}$. Let $V_{\beta}$ be the space spanned by vectors $\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \dotsc, \beta_{s}$. It is given that $(\alpha_{i},\alpha_{j}) = (\beta_{i},\beta_{j})$ for all $i,j \in \{1,\dotsc,s\}$. We want to find an orthogonal transformation $\mathcal{A}$ from $V_{\alpha}$ to $V_{\beta}$.

**The Transformation:** Any vector $x$ in $V_{\alpha}$ can be expressed in the following form $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$ for some scalars $a_{i} \in \mathbb{R}$. We define the transformation $\mathcal{A}$ as follows:
$$\mathcal{A}(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot \beta_{i}$$.

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{A}(x) \in V_{\beta}$ since it is a linear combination of vectors $\beta_{1}, \dotsc, \beta_{s}$. Moreover, $\alpha_{j}$ is mapped to $\beta_{j}$ since we can set $a_{j} = 1$ and $a_{i} = 0$ for all $i \in \{1,\dotsc,s\} \setminus \{j\}$.

To show that $\mathcal{A}$ is [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation), we need to prove that it is a *linear transformation* and it *preserves the inner product*. The proof goes as follows:

1. **$\mathcal{A}$ is Linear Transformation:** We need to show that for any two vectors $x,y \in V_{\alpha}$,  $\mathcal{A}(x+y) = \mathcal{A}(x) + \mathcal{A}(y)$ and $\mathcal{A}(c \cdot x) = c \cdot \mathcal{A}(x)$ for any constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Using the above definition of $\mathcal{A}$ it is easy to prove both these properties. Therefore, $\mathcal{A}$ is a linear transformation.
2. **$\mathcal{A}$ preserves the inner product:** We need to show that for any two vectors $x,y \in V_{\alpha}$, $(x,y) = (\mathcal{A}(x),\mathcal{A}(y))$. Let $x = \sum_{i = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$ and $y = \sum_{i = 1}^{s} b_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$. The proof goes as follows:
   \begin{align*}
   (x,y) &= \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i} \right)^{T} \cdot \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{s} b_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i} \right) \\
   &= \sum_{i = 1}^{s} \sum_{j = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot b_{i} \cdot (\alpha_{i},\alpha_{j}) \\
   &= \sum_{i = 1}^{s} \sum_{j = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot b_{i} \cdot (\beta_{i},\beta_{j}) \quad \textrm{$\because$ it is given that $(\alpha_{i},\alpha_{j}) = (\beta_{i},\beta_{j})$}\\
   &= \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{s} a_{i} \cdot \beta_{i} \right)^{T} \cdot \left(\sum_{i = 1}^{s} b_{i} \cdot \beta_{i} \right) \\
   &= (\mathcal{A}(x))^{T} \cdot (\mathcal{A}(y)) \\
   &= (\mathcal{A}(x),\mathcal{A}(y))
   \end{align*}
   This proves that $\mathcal{A}$ is an orthogonal transformation.

---

Note that any vector $x \in \mathcal{A}$ can be expressed in multiple forms. However, it will still get mapped to the same $\mathcal{A}(x)$. In other words, the transformation $\mathcal{A}$ is bijective. To prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is one-to-one; suppose a vector $x \in \mathcal{A}(x)$ has two forms say $\sum_{i = 1}^{s}a_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{s}b_{i} \cdot \alpha_{i}$; then both these forms will map to the same $\mathcal{A}(x)$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose these two maps to vectors say $y = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}a_{i} \cdot \beta_{i}$ and $z = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}b_{i} \cdot \beta_{i}$; and $y\neq z$. Then $\| y-z\| \neq 0$. It contradicts the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ preserves the pairwise distances. In the same way, we can show that function is onto. This proves that $\mathcal{A}$ is indeed bijective.